# awk to match fields condition from two files

Tags: awk

Would like to match Input.csv file based on field `$2 (Country)` And field `$4 (Type)` with Ref.csv
If it matches, then need to print entire line from Input.csv and corresponding Amount field from Ref.csv
If it is not match, then print entire line from Input.csv and "NotFound"

```
For example: Country= "Angola" and Type="Voice"  then need to print the value from $3 (Amount=10) Ref.csv
         Country= "Angola" and Type="Data"   then need to print the value from $4 (Amount=20) Ref.csv   
         Country= "Angola" and Type="SMS"    then need to print the value from $5 (Amount=30) Ref.csv   

         Country= "Yemen" is not available in the Ref.csv , so need to print as "NotFound"
```

Input.csv

```
Month,Country,Desc,Type
Nov'2017,Angola,abc,Voice
Nov'2017,Angola,xxx,Voice
Nov'2017,Angola,abc,Data
Nov'2017,Angola,abc,SMS
Nov'2017,Brazil,def,Data
Nov'2017,Brazil,def,Voice
Nov'2017,Yemen,yyy,Data
Nov'2017,Zambia,ghi,SMS
Nov'2017,Zambia,xxx,SMS
Nov'2017,Zimbabwe,yyy,Voice
```

Ref.csv

```
Country,Desc,Voice,Data,SMS
Albania,abc,5,10,15
Angola,def,10,20,30
Bahrain,ghi,2,4,6
Brazil,jkl,45,30,15
Zambia,mno,5,7,9
```

Expected Output.csv

```
Month,Country,Desc,Type,Amount
Nov'2017,Angola,abc,Voice,10
Nov'2017,Angola,xxx,Voice,10
Nov'2017,Angola,abc,Data,20
Nov'2017,Angola,abc,SMS,30
Nov'2017,Brazil,def,Data,30
Nov'2017,Brazil,def,Voice,45
Nov'2017,Yemen,yyy,Data,NotFound
Nov'2017,Zambia,ghi,SMS,9
Nov'2017,Zambia,xxx,SMS,9
Nov'2017,Zimbabwe,yyy,Voice,NotFound
```

Looking for your suggestions ...!!!

**Edit Command #1**

```
awk 'BEGIN  { FS=OFS="," }
      NR==1{print $0,"Amount"; next} {
      map[$1,"Voice"]=$3
      map[$1,"Data"]=$4
      map[$1,"SMS"]=$5
(($2","$4) in map ) { print $0,map[f2,f4] }  else { print $0,"NotFound" }
}' Ref.csv Input.csv
```

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: Writing the question and then tagging a tool doesn't help I am afraid :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
    NR == FNR {
        for (i=3; i<=NF; i++)
            if (FNR == 1)
                head[i] = $i
            else
                ref[$1,head[i]] = $i
        next
    }
    FNR == 1 {print $0, "Amount"; next}
    {
        amount = (($2,$4) in ref) ? ref[$2,$4] : "NotFound"
        print $0, amount
    }
' Ref.csv Input.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this script within the same directory where your input files are located.

```
#!/bin/sh
cat Input.csv | while read line
do
  country=`echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $2}'`
  type=`echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $4}'`
  ref=`grep -i $country Ref.csv`

  if [ -z "$ref" ];
  then
    echo $line,NotFound;
  else
    case $type in
      "Voice")
        data=`echo $ref | awk -F ',' '{print $3}'`
      ;;
    esac
    case $type in
      "Data")
        data=`echo $ref | awk -F ',' '{print $4}'`
      ;;
    esac
    case $type in
      "SMS")
        data=`echo $ref | awk -F ',' '{print $5}'`
      ;;
    esac

    echo $line,$data; 
  fi;

done;
```

I tested it and it outputs exactly what you want.

Comment: You should have 1 case statement with 3 patterns, not 3 case statements.

Comment: You are right! I just copy-pasted the first case in a hurry.